# Strongly-typed languages for web programming

Tags: programming-languages, strong-typing

Are there any strongly-typed programming languages for the Web? I program in PHP now, but often I wish it yelled at me when I tried to compare a number to a string. Functions in the standard library that can return either a bool or an integer don't make anything easier either.

I know there's .NET, but is it my **only** choice?

Comment: Are you looking for strongly-typed, or statically typed?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system

Comment: Strongly-typed and either statically- or dynamically-typed.

Comment: If you wish "it" (assuming you mean your IDE/compiler) to yell at you when you compare a number to a string, then Java is a better answer than Python. Java is statically-typed and Python is dynamically-typed.

Answer (score 7):

You can develop Java web-applications. See [JSPs.](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/)

Comment: While (maybe) still valid in 2009, this should not be the highest-voted answer in 2015 :) Java is a perfect suggestion just not JSP

Answer (score 6):

Java? C++? Any language can be a web language...  More details on your requirements would be needed to make a specific recommendation.

Python is a powerful, and popular dynamic strong typed language for web development:

- [PyWeb](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/pyweb/)
- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/)
- [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt#/) is a good C++ web framework

Comment: I pity the fool who tries to use C++ for web development. Java is tolerable, though.

Comment: Regarding web development using C++ you may want to check out http://pocoproject.org/

Comment: @JS Bangs, Are you speaking from experience of from some things you've heard?

Comment: CPPCMS can be a good start if performances are criticals : http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Python is strongly-typed, and [widely used for web](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebProgramming).

Answer (score 5):

You can use Java for web development. You would then need Tomcat or another Servlet Container that supports the deployment of Java Servlets and JSPs.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 3):

There is an [OCaml web programming framework](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~balat/publications/2009icfp-ocsigen.pdf), and OCaml is strongly and statically typed if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) - a framework for web development using [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) is a web development framework for [C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Seaside](http://www.seaside.st/) is a web-framework for Smalltalk.