# strongly typed php alternative

Tags: php, strong-typing

I've been programming in PHP for several years now, but I also have some experience in other languages like java, c++, c# etc. I think PHP is a good language for web development, but I really miss some features from the other languages, mostly that PHP is weak typed, and real (operator) overloading is not possible. So now I'm looking for an alternative. I've already tried asp.net (c# mvc), and I really liked that language, but it is windows only, and I want a language which can run on linux based systems.

So do you have any suggestions? I want:

- a strongly typed language

  good mysql support

  function overloading (preferably even operator overloading)

  OOP

  useful for web development

Comment: You can run asp.net web applications on linux servers using Mono.

Comment: didn't knew that, I think I'm gonna take a look for that, since I've worked with asp.net before. Tx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861546/strongly-typed-languages-for-web-programming). Python seems to be highly recommended in the answers and satisfies all of your criteria except function overloading unfortunately. That said Java and C# both sound a lot like what you may be looking for, and can both be run on linux based systems.

The [Django Framework](http://www.djangoproject.com/) is a python based web development framework that should let you develop web sites using Python if you choose that route.

Comment: +1 Actually just started confronting the same questions as the OP and picked up some Python books today.

Comment: C# is relatively good in the web market when run on Mono. Desktop stuff on mono is a bit weak, The only big missing feature I've seen in my day-to-day mono and .Net usage is that Mono doesn't support Linq very well at the moment.

Comment: I'm personally a huge fan of C# and ASP.NET and there are a ton of jobs for it as well. A valuable skill all around.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but if you liked C# and ASP.NET MVC maybe you should look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

Answer (score 2):

Try [Haxe](http://haxe.org/). It has a very strong typing and can be compiled to other languages, for example to PHP, so you have all the power of strong typing and flexibility to deploy it to any cheap PHP-driven hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you like C++, and can write portable code(code that works between Linux and Windows) then you may look at one of the many [C++ web frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework).

Personally though, I couldn't imagine such a large amount of string manipulation in C++ :P

Comment: I've had a look at c++ for web development before, but although I like c++ very much, it just isn't suited for webpdevelopment.

Comment: @Tiddo, that is my feelings on it as well, but just informing you that there are people insane enough to make web applications in C++ :P